# CI Error on libraries\Form_validation.php on line 450

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a controller with:

```
if($_POST) {
      $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $val = $this->form_validation;

      $val->set_rules('content[title]', 'Title', 'trim|required');
      $val->set_rules('content[subtitle]', 'Subtitle', 'trim');
      $val->set_rules('content[description]', 'description', 'trim');

      if ($val->run() AND $this->db->insert('content', $content)) {
        // query done
      }
  }
```

When I post form I am getting this error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::load() in **...\libraries\Form_validation.php** on line 450

Line of 450 of `Form_validation.php`

```
// Load the language file containing error messages
$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');
```

Please help me fix this....

Comment: try to load library before post, may this will help

Comment: @Farhan not helps... The same error.

Comment: @Sinto load->lang() is in CI system file. It was not written by me

Comment: did you call parent constructor ?

Comment: i'm not sure but it looks like that you somehow overwrite the `lang` variable in CI, do you've any library, object or anything like that which is called by `lang` ?

Comment: @Farhan you mean CI_Controller ?? Yes It called with __contruct() function

Comment: @sintakonte No, there was not any changes with `lang` variable. I have a changes only with `application` folder

Comment: this doesnt matter - make a `print_r($this->lang);` after your line `if($_POST)` and post the content of that...

Comment: @sintakonte, Thank you bro, you was right. I was created variable with name `$this->lang` on parent class. I changed its name. Now it is working ! :)

Comment: I had a variable with name `$this->lang = $this->SiteModel->siteLanguage();` and I changed it to `$this->mylang = $this->SiteModel->siteLanguage();`

Answer (score 1):

replace your `input names` with title, subtitle, description and try this code

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 if ($this->input->post()) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subtitle', 'Subtitle', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Description', 'required');

        $data['content'] = array(
            'db_field_name' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'db_field_name' => $this->input->post('subtitle'),
            'db_field_name' => $this->input->post('description'),
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->db->insert('content', $data['content']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form validation and all for multiple instance you can define the helper and library in the config/autoload.php. Also refer the input_field name for validation rule.

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subtitle', 'Subtitle', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Description', 'required');      

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        //Your DB operation
        $this->data['formdata'] = array(
            'db_field_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'db_field_subtitle' => $this->input->post('subtitle'),
            'db_field_description' => $this->input->post('description')
        );
        $this->db->insert('content', $this->data['content']);
    } else {
        //Show error message
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i think there is missing of language file
        You have to check that in **system/language/english folder** there is form_validation_lang.php is available or not.  there is missing of form_Validation_lang.php you have to put that file